# Biber version in MikTex (2.16) doesn't match version applied for compiling (2.12)

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber, miktex2.9

I am using LuaLatex and have a pretty strange problem for me regarding Biber and Biblatex. MikTex tells me my installed versions for Biber and BibLatex are:
biber-windows-x64 (2.16)
biber-doc (2.16)
biblatex (3.16)

[image: Screen-shot package version of biber-windows-x64]

However, when I want to compile my main.tex through TexStudio it gets stuck running continuously with only minor warnings in the main.log.

[image: Screen-shot of the main.log messages]

My main.blg-file on the other hand tells me the following:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.12
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
[27] biber-MSWIN64:315> INFO - === 
[51] Biber.pm:371> INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
[171] Utils.pm:209> ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.7, expected version 3.5.
This means that your biber (2.12) and biblatex (3.16) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
[171] Biber.pm:114> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

How can I solve this issue? Where I have to look for?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: run on a command line `where biber` to check which one is used.  And check for updates in the miktex console in user *and* admin mode.

Comment: You have a shared/system-wide MIkTeX install, so the first step would indeed be to update both in Admin and User mode as Ulrike suggests. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 for help with that. If that does not resolve the issue, then the most likely explanation is that you have multiple instances of Biber on your machine and MikTeX updates one of them, but your editor uses another. Check your editors settings to see which Biber it calls. Then check which Bibers your command line finds with `where biber`.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike and moewe, the update could have been one of the reasons. Additionally I decided to not use any template anymore and just started with an all new `\documentclass{scrbook}` including only the packages I really need for now. Maybe this was the issue as well eventhough commented out most of the options of the templates.